# Weird diagonal plot with gnuplot plot with images

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to plot 3 variables, where the third column defines the colour palette. The code is called by another program. The data file has scattered data points which are ":" (colon) separated.

The script file used:

```
reset
set title "Cluster Properties"
set datafile separator ":"
outfile = sprintf("%s%s", ARG2, "ClusterCount2.png")
set output  outfile
set term pngcairo size 1920, 1080 enhanced font 'Verdana,30'
x_tk = sprintf("%s%s%s", "Sweeps ( X ", ARG6, " )")
set xtics 1,1
set ytics 1,1 font ", 20"
set ytics add (2)
set xlabel x_tk
set ylabel "Cluster Size (Particles)"
set zlabel "Number of Clusters"
set cblabel "Number of Clusters"
set cbtics 0,1 font ", 20"
set autoscale xfix
set yrange [1:*]
set view map

set y2tics 1,1

set grid front xtics y2tics lw 1.5 lt -1 lc rgb 'white'


unset key
plot ARG1 using ($1/ARG6):2:3 with image

reset
```

Gives the following output:

**Problematic Plot**:

[image: Problematic Plot]

While with doing the same with less data points:

**Okay Plot**:

[image: Okay Plot]

Link to the data file: [Drive Link to data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jmGS9v0iHys0eI3AQnR4nWjNhhOqM0jz/view?usp=sharing)

Can someone help me with this, I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: It would help to show the data which produced the odd diagonal plot.  Also, are you sure that the command you used was `plot` rather than `splot`?  The script includes a line `set view map` that is only relevant to plots made with `splot`.

Comment: @Ethan I was using pm3d earlier, I think I forgot to remove that line(That shouldn't be the cause of the problem?). I have edited the post and included the datafile link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data file does not contain a line for each pixel in the implied image.
I.e. there are 11 points with x value 50000, 25 with x value 100000, 39 with x value 150000, ...  When the program tries to figure out the number of horizontal and vertical pixels in the image it sees 11 points with the same x coordinate and thinks Aha! one of the image dimensions is 11.  But then after reading the entire data file it knows there are 738 pixels total, and tries to make it an 11xSomething  rectangle.  That obviously doesn't work and it ends up drawing 11 pixels on each vertical line but staggering them to fill the full range of coordinates seen.

In short, your data file does not actually describe a full rectangular array of pixels that can be rendered as an image. You could modify the procedure used to generate the file so that the entire rectangle is filled in, or plot `with points pt 5` rather than `with image`.

Here is the output from

```
gnuplot> set pointsize 4
gnuplot> plot 'clusterstat.dat' using ($1/5.e5):2:3 with point pt 5 lc palette
```

Obviously you would want to further adjust the point size, axis ratio, placement of labels etc, but it shows what is there in the data.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ethan for the amazing answer. I guess there is no way to specify the range explicitly when plotting through images. I tried producing heatmaps with pm3d but the z-range (cbrange) was giving absurd value - some sort of scaling was taking place. Do you think that is a good alternative?